# How to properly set up the admin role in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using "devise" and "namespaced" to make the administration of a website but the method "admin?" (current_user.admin?), where did it come from ? if its supposed to be a field on my table "user"? when it became a method?

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authorize_admin!

  def index
  end

  private
    def authorize_admin!
      authenticate_user!
      unless current_user.admin?
        redirect_to root_path, alert: "You must be an admin to do that."
     end 
  end
end
```

Comment: If you have a field `admin` on a model, then activerecord will generate methods `admin`, `admin?` (and a bunch of others)

Comment: Adding up, the field should be of boolean type.

Comment: I am sure you did this `rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean` from devise wiki and it create predicator methods of bool return like `admin?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of add an administrator to your app is not very functional, what if you need to add more roles?

My suggestion is to use a gem for your roles like [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify), with Rolify you can create any role, and use a gem [for allow and deny perms](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) like Cancancan

For example with Rolify you can add the `admin` role like this:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

Then with Cancancan you can define perms for each controller action or per set of controller actions, let's say you have a model `Post` and only admins can manage them:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
       can :manage, :all
    else
       can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

The above is telling rails that the `:admin` role can manage all the models in your app, and all the other roles (including guest users) can read all the models in your app. For more information about defining perms check the [Wiki of Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities)

Now if you want to show a message when a user is trying to enter to a non-authorized resource you can rescue the exception of Cancancan:

```
#In your application_controller.rb
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    if exception.message.match(/are not/i)
        redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Oouch... no estás autorizado para acceder a esta página"
    else
        redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
    end
 end
```

Rolify and Cancancan integrate smoothly with Devise, so this is the right now for creating roles and perms in your app. I hope have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one of two ways:

One, as @SergioTulentsev answered: you can add a column name `admin` with a data type of boolean, default value is false.
- you create migration file with command:

```
rails g migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

- after that you go on that migration file edit:

  `def change
      add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: fase
   end`
- after that run: `rake db:migrate`
- when you want check whether current user is admin? you only use `current_user.admin?`

Alternatively you can create an instance method in user model to check whether  user is admin.
For example in user model you create method:

```
def admin?
  seff.name == "admin"
end
```

as soon as you can check follow: `current_user.admin?`

Answer (score -2):

admin maybe a function defined in you Model User  some gems like cancancan can help you